# How to Interpolate in Circular Meshgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I am trying to get an interpolated "Heatmap" (circular/polar cords) for 5 Samples on a laboratory table of r=85 mm. What i wanted to get is an interpolated "Map". The Samples have different positions on the table and i have a dB-Value for every Sample (so to call the z value/coordinate). Is it possible to interpolate over the entire circular meshgrid so that a get something like a Heatmap for the whole table?

I am currently stuck at this and have no idea how to go on.

Here is the Code I have written so far, but it doesn't look the way i expected.

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Points within the circle (radius 85mm) corresponding to the sample 
position on a circ. measuring table of r=85mm
max_r = 85
max_theta = 2*np.pi
number_points = 5
points = np.array([[64,(-6/8)*np.pi], [64,(6/8)*np.pi], [0, 0],[60, 
(-2/8)*np.pi],[60, (2/8)*np.pi]])  # [r,theta] of the specific Sample 
position

# The Measured Values in dB-Scale ("z"-Values) for the five Samples
values = [-38.469016,-38.159216 ,-36.763974,-36.208431 ,-36.004596]

# create grid
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2*np.pi, 50)
r = np.linspace(0, max_r, 50)
grid_r, grid_theta = np.meshgrid(r, theta)
data = griddata(points, values, (grid_r, grid_theta), method='cubic', 
fill_value=0)


# Create a polar projection
ax1 = plt.subplot(projection="polar")
ax1.pcolormesh(theta, r, data.T)
ax1.set_rmax(85)
plt.show()
```

I am thankfull for every help.
Best regards
Bastian

Here are two plots, one with the right position of the samples on the meshgrid,one from the code above.

[image: Position of Samples]

[image: Plot from the Code above]

Comment: You only have five samples, maybe stretching it a bit far interpolating!

Comment: Hi, you are right. But there are coming more samples in the future, this is for "how to do it". So i am trying to write a code to test and then get more samples.

Comment: Ok well its a nice question, sorry I don't think I can help.

Comment: First of all, your data ranges from -pi to pi, but your interpolation grid ranges from 0 to 2pi. So you loose half the data. Then you will need to take into account that you will need a value at 0 for each theta direction. Finally you probably want to close the circle, i.e. repeat the first theta value at the end (e.g. if your circle goes from 0 to 2pi, give 0 as well as 2pi the same value to have it closed).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks a lot for that comment! I am closer to the solution now. For every theta-position I added an r_0 value, so that i have a radial closed Plot. As soon as i figured out the rest, i will post the solution in here.