Interpolating 3D heat map in matplotlib (XY,C)
I have plotted X,Y co-ordinates in a 2D polar-plot, and I am passing a third value to each co-ordinate that is my third dimension. I am trying to the interpolate between all plotted points, similar to the example found here: Circular interpolated heat map plot using python.
I am however not getting the result I am expecting.
Below is my shortened code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

### INTENSITY VALUES FOR HEATMAP ###

T1 = 100,100,100,100,100,100,50,50,50,50,50,50,1,1,1,1,1,1,

### CO-ORDINATES ###

a=0
b=0
rO = 7.5
rM = 5
rI = 2.5
heights =  1,2,3,4,5

### RADIAL POINTS ###

def XCoords(a,rO,rM,rI):
    XsX = []
    O = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,6,endpoint=False)
    for i in O:
        xx = a+rO*np.cos(i),a+rM*np.cos(i),a+rI*np.cos(i)
        XsX.append(xx)
    return XsX

Xs1,Xs2,Xs3 = np.column_stack(XCoords(a,rO,rM,rI))
        
def YCoords(b,rO,rM,rI):
    YsY = []
    O = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,6,endpoint=False)
    for i in O:
        yy = a+rO*np.sin(i),a+rM*np.sin(i),a+rI*np.sin(i)
        YsY.append(yy)
    return YsY

Ys1,Ys2,Ys3 = np.column_stack(YCoords(b,rO,rM,rI))

def cart2pol(x,y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y,x)
    return (rho,phi)

PolarR1, PolarT1 = cart2pol(Xs1,Ys1)
PolarR2, PolarT2 = cart2pol(Xs2,Ys2)
PolarR3, PolarT3 = cart2pol(Xs3,Ys3)

PolarRF = PolarR1,PolarR2,PolarR3
PolarTF = PolarT1,PolarT2,PolarT3

### INTERPOLATION ATTEMPT ###

max_r = 7.5
max_theta = 2*np.pi
theta = np.linspace(0,max_theta,200)
r = np.linspace(0,max_r,200)
grid_r,grid_theta = np.meshgrid(r,theta)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(PolarRF,PolarTF)

points = np.column_stack((X.flatten(),Y.flatten()))  
values = np.linspace(np.min(T1),np.max(T1),324)

data = griddata(points,values,(grid_r,grid_theta),method='nearest',fill_value=0,rescale=False)

### HEAT MAP COLORS ###

grad = 'viridis'

cA = T1
mB = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=grad)
fAcolors = mB.to_rgba(cA)

### PLOT ###

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(121,projection='polar')
ax.scatter(PolarTF,PolarRF,s=200,c=fAcolors,alpha=0.5)

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15),dpi=300)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,projection='polar')
ax2.pcolormesh(grid_theta,grid_r,data,alpha=0.5)


plt.show()

This code produces the plot:

I am unable to get the second plot to have a distribution that is similar to the first. I'm unsure what I am doing wrong. I have tried changing which method I use, and this doesn't produce the results I want either.

What kind of interpolation are you trying to do? Do you want the second plot to vary continuously in colour? In a linear fashion, or otherwise?

@Reinderien I am trying to do a radial interpolation, where the data from the co-ordinates is used to fill the space between the points, from the center to the outer circle. The example at the bottom of this link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html is what I am trying to do more or less.

Are you sure you want to use (1, 50, 100)? That's an irregular grid. I would expect (0, 50, 100).

@Reinderien, those numbers are the intensities values, so they shouldn't be affecting the grid no?

It doesn't seem like you should be invoking scipy's interpolation; instead, you just want continuous (Gouraud) shading on pcolormesh.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polar_rf = np.array((2.5, 5.0, 7.5))
t1_intensities = np.array((1, 50, 100))
theta = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2*np.pi, num=51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(theta, polar_rf)
C = np.broadcast_to(t1_intensities[:, np.newaxis], shape=X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, C, shading='gouraud')
plt.show()



Hi Reinderien! Thanks for this example, it looks like what I am after exactly.
Since I am dealing with real data, I had the thought that interpolating over the data I measure will allow me to extract a function that I can use to calculate the intensity in unmeasured areas. Would what you have shown here do that?
I was under the impression I would need interpolation.
What I am trying to do is very similiar to this older post I just found (no solution unfortunately). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137584/how-to-interpolate-in-circular-meshgrid

What "unmeasured areas" do you need to access? You haven't shown this in the question.

everything in the 7.5 Radius circle, that isn't a measured point ideally. Sorry I should have stated that in my original post as my motivation for interpolation.

You can't have "everything". That would be an infinite number of points, and you don't have that much memory.

apologies, I don't mean literally everything, rather just the maximum number of points possible.

That's not how it works. Any useful data processing is going to have specific points to interpolate, and those points are typically not going to be very numerous. They especially shouldn't be numerous given how low-detail your initial data are. Without describing what you're actually trying to do after the interpolation, it's impossible to provide a more specific explanation.

I might remake the post then with the things you pointed out in mind.
If it helps with this point, the data is coming from temperature measurements (the values here are made up), where I would measure the temperature of liquid in a cup in the middle, then outwardly as shown in the first plot. With that information, I wanted to generate a heatmap by interpolating all of the measured points. I then wanted to use the interpolated data to check how accurate the interpolation is. By generating a function from middle to outer, then evaluating.

It sounds like you don't want to interpolate at all; you want to find a best-fit function of temperature against radius.

is not a best-fit function and an interpolation nearly the same thing? I am also wanting the visual representation of the interpolation as a heat map.

They are not at all the same thing

Hi @Reinderien, don't mean to "@" you, but I have posted my solution.
If you have any feedback I'd greatly appreciate it.

it's a whole lot of code that misses the point.

could you elaborate?

Update: I have found a way to make this work. My biggest issue was not having the three variables gridtdf, gridrdf, and data3.T in the correct forms to match up correctly, which was causing me issues.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd

### INTENSITY VALUES FOR HEATMAP ###

Ti = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Tmi = 25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25
Tm = 50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50
To = 100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100

Tall = Ti,Tmi,Tm,To
Tarr = np.array(Tall)
Tcs = np.column_stack(Tarr)
Tdf = pd.DataFrame(Tall)

Tzall = To+Tm+Tmi+Ti

T1r = []
for i in Tdf:
    xx = Tdf.iloc[:,i]
    T1r.append(xx)
    
T1rr = pd.concat(T1r)

### CO-ORDINATES ###

a=0
b=0
rO = 7.5
rM = 5.5
rMi = 3.5
rI = 1.5
heights =  1,2,3,4,5

### RADIAL POINTS ###

def XCoords(a,rO,rM,rMi,rI):
    XsX = []
    O = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,15,endpoint=True)
    for i in O:
        xx = (a+rI*np.cos(i)),(a+rMi*np.cos(i)),(a+rM*np.cos(i)),(a+rO*np.cos(i))
        XsX.append(xx)
    return XsX

Xs1,Xs2,Xs3,Xs4 = np.column_stack(XCoords(a,rO,rM,rMi,rI))

Xss = np.array(XCoords(a,rO,rM,rMi,rI))
Xssdf = pd.DataFrame(Xss)

Xfi = []
for i in Xssdf:
    xx = Xssdf.iloc[:,i]
    Xfi.append(xx)
Xfii = pd.concat(Xfi)

def YCoords(b,rO,rM,rMi,rI):
    YsY = []
    O = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,15,endpoint=True)
    for i in O:
        yy = a+rI*np.sin(i),a+rMi*np.sin(i),a+rM*np.sin(i),a+rO*np.sin(i)
        YsY.append(yy)
    return YsY

Ys1,Ys2,Ys3,Ys4 = np.column_stack(YCoords(b,rO,rM,rMi,rI))

Yss = np.array(YCoords(b,rO,rM,rMi,rI))
Yssdf = pd.DataFrame(Yss)

Yfi = []
for i in Yssdf:
    xx = Yssdf.iloc[:,i]
    Yfi.append(xx)
Yfii = pd.concat(Yfi)

def cart2pol(x,y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y,x)
    return (rho,phi)

PolarR1, PolarT1 = cart2pol(Xs1,Ys1)
PolarR2, PolarT2 = cart2pol(Xs2,Ys2)
PolarR3, PolarT3 = cart2pol(Xs3,Ys3)
PolarR4, PolarT4 = cart2pol(Xs4,Ys4)

PolarRF = PolarR4,PolarR3,PolarR2,PolarR1
PolarTF = PolarT4,PolarT3,PolarT2,PolarT1

### INTERPOLATION ATTEMPT ###

max_r = 7.5
max_theta = 2*np.pi
theta = np.linspace(0,max_theta,500)
r = np.linspace(0,max_r,500)
grid_r,grid_theta = np.meshgrid(r,theta)

gridrdf = pd.DataFrame(grid_r)

gridtdf = pd.DataFrame(grid_theta)

def pol2cart(rho, phi):
    x = rho * np.cos(phi)
    y = rho * np.sin(phi)
    return(x, y)

gridx, gridy = pol2cart(grid_r,grid_theta)

points = np.column_stack(((Xfii,Yfii)))
pointsdf = pd.DataFrame(points)

vals = []
for i in Tdf:
    length = int(len(pointsdf)/15)
    test = np.linspace(np.min(Tdf.iloc[:,i]),np.max(Tdf.iloc[:,i]),length)
    vals.append(test)

valsdf = pd.DataFrame(vals)
valscon = []
for i in valsdf:
    xx = (valsdf.iloc[:,i])
    valscon.append(xx)
    
valsf = pd.concat(valscon)

data = griddata(pointsdf,valsf,(gridx,gridy),method='linear',fill_value=100,rescale=False)
data2 = np.column_stack(data)
data3 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

### HEAT MAP COLORS ###

grad = 'viridis'

cA = Tzall
mB = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=grad)
fAcolors = mB.to_rgba(cA)

### PLOT ###

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(121,projection='polar')
ax.scatter(PolarTF,PolarRF,s=200,c=fAcolors,alpha=1)

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15),dpi=300)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,projection='polar')
ax2.pcolormesh(gridtdf,gridrdf,data3.T,alpha=1)


plt.show()



Let's discuss in Interpolating 3D heat map in matplotlib (XY,C).

@Reinderien, I don't have the reputation to talk in that thread

First, your data are clearly fake, and when they become "real", the way that they become real changes which solution you'll want to pursue. You say the data is coming from temperature measurements (the values here are made up), where I would measure the temperature of liquid in a cup in the middle, then outwardly as shown in the first plot.
If that's not a lie, then that means that you don't have 3D data, and you'll never have 3D data. That reduces the problem to two dimensions.

Perhaps more importantly, I wanted to generate a heatmap by interpolating all of the measured points. I then wanted to use the interpolated data to check how accurate the interpolation is is circular logic and fairly unhelpful. So long as we trust the implementers of the Scipy routines (and we nearly always do), it's pointless to "check interpolation accuracy". Interpolation will always run through the input points, so it's perfectly accurate. It's meaningless to worry about interpolation accuracy unless you have much more detailed domain knowledge of the data, the temperature in your case.

If you're only plotting, use the method I showed. If you're not only plotting, then you need to put more effort into describing what you're actually doing. Your generating a function from middle to outer, then evaluating can mean a lot of different things. Do you mean showing a function of best approximation in algebraic form? If so, that's not interpolation, it's fitting.

@Reinderien, it is fake in this example, although I did explicitly state that.
It is 3D data in the sense that I have X,Y coordinates, and a third dimension, that is temperature. That is 3 dimensions of data.
What I want to do is use measured data, (X,Y and Temp) and plot it. Then interpolate. Then I would want to measure the temperature in the interpolated areas, where I hadn't previously measured temps, and check to see if it matches with the calculated values.

That doesn't make sense. By design, interpolated values will never match measured values. Interpolated values will always be between measured values.

@ Reinderien, I'm not looking to make them match, I want to see how well the interpolation can predict/approximate the measured value

That's kind of a value-less exercise. Of course any interpolation will exactly match the input points at the input points, and assessing anything between them requires a more sophisticated understanding of the model - linear? polynomial? something else? In real life, a typical workflow would go: measure (many, many more points than what you've shown); choose a model based on physics; fit the model; then decide whether the model has too much error. Asking "is the interpolation accurate" is about as useful as asking "is the average of 1 and 2 really 1.5? Are we absolutely sure about that?"

@Reinderien,You are confused. I am not trying to match the input points. I am measuring data points, interpolating, and then checking if the interpolated points match the remeasured data points.
